# Automation Error when adding worksheet

Tags: excel, vba

I am having issues with adding multiple worksheets with names. Once I create the file, save it and start to add worksheets it is ok but crashes (automation error/exception occurred - requires restart of Excel, etc.) when it tries to add the 3rd worksheet (named "DPG"). Below is the section of the code that has the issue:

```
'CREATE DATA OUTPUT FILE
Set NewBook = Workbooks.Add
    With NewBook
        .Title = "DATA OUTPUT"
        .Subject = "OUTPUT"
        .SaveAs Filename:="H:\REACKS\DATA OUTPUT.xls"
    End With

Worksheets.Add().Name = "ALL"
Worksheets.Add().Name = "CORP"
Worksheets.Add().Name = "DPG"
Worksheets.Add().Name = "ESG"
Worksheets.Add().Name = "FSG"
Worksheets.Add().Name = "KEN"
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: I'm not able to replicate this and it's working fine on my machine. Does it break if you just do the Worksheets.Add() without setting the name?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the problem! It wasn't saving it properly as an .xls, even though it was specified in the file name. I added a file format definition set to .xls.

```
    .SaveAs Filename:="H:\REACKS\DATA OUTPUT.xls", FileFormat:=xlExcel8
```

That seemed to do the trick!

Answer (score 0):

Add this line `NewBook.Activate` **before** the first `Worksheets.Add()...`

**Edit :** Nvm, that didn't work. Instead, try this :

```
Dim NewBook As Workbook

Set NewBook = Workbooks.Add
With NewBook
    .Title = "DATA OUTPUT"
    .Subject = "OUTPUT"
    .SaveAs Filename:="C:\Documents and Settings\rfavron\Bureau\Bernard\DATA OUTPUT.xls"
    .Worksheets.Add().Name = "ALL"
    .Worksheets.Add().Name = "CORP"
    .Worksheets.Add().Name = "DPG"
    .Worksheets.Add().Name = "ESG"
    .Worksheets.Add().Name = "FSG"
    .Worksheets.Add().Name = "KEN"
End With
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, but it didn't work. It still crashes on the third worksheet add.